# Encode 256 Palletized bitmaps to h264 using libav

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

Am converting 32 bpp bitmap to 8bpp with 256 color pallete, this image i want to encode using h264 and send it over socket. And on the other end decode the frame and display it on my UI.

From Encoder, side:

1. Capture 32 bpp image.
2. Quantize the image to 8bpp with 256 color pallete.
3. Sws_scale the image from PIX_FMT_GRAY8 to YUV420P.
4. Encode it with h264 and send it over socket.

From Decoder, side.

1. Receive image.
2. Decode image.
3. Sws_scale from YUV420P to PIX_FMT_GRAY8
4. And display it on UI along with palette information(Sent from Encoder over socket).

When the above steps are followed, i get a totally distorted image. And when i dont use the color palette i get a black and white image.

Am not not clear how to encode the 8bpp 256 palette bitmaps using h264 and decode them accordingly. Please help me regarding this.

Am working with C++ on windows platform.

Thanks in advance,
Paul.

Answer (score 1):

h.264 is not (by default) a lossless codec. So you will not get the exact color out that you put in on a pixel by pixel basis. In YUV the Y plan is luminance (black and white) and the UV planes are chroma. So your UV planes are empty here. The Y plane is compressed in a lossy fashion. so you may have a pallet that looks like 0=black 1=red 2=green ... 255=white. And you put in a 2 pixel. During the compression, to remove complexity in the image to reduce file size, the 2 may become a 1. In a black and white image you will not notice the difference. But when you apply your pallet, you green pixel just turned red.

You either need to use a a lossless codec, or encode your 256 color image to a YUV color image. Then post decode re-qunatize the colors back to your desired pallet by finding the closest color or each decoded pixel.

Comment: hi szatmary, Thanks for throwing some light, can u please guide me to some C or C++ library, which can convert 256 color images to YUV image as am very new to this field.

Comment: Libswscale will do it.

Comment: and how can i re quantize the image, is there any library for this?

Comment: I don't know, maybe. You just need to find the 'closest' color in you palette. A 3d Euclidian distance is probably not a good way to go. Maybe PSNR? I would open another question asking this to get an answer from somebody that knows more about color theory than me.